Visibility Permissions on Archived Items
In Sitecore 8.2, we recently had an incident where a user accidentally archived an item and a second user had to help recover it because the first user couldn't see it in the archive.  Both users have identical roles assigned to them, so I inferred that the second user had additional permissions at the user level.
I'm trying to verify this, but I don't know where to look to find access permissions for archived items.  (I'm also rather curious whether permissions for an item are carried with them when they get archived or whether different access rules get applied to the item at that point.)  Can anyone enlighten me?

I experienced similar issues as well. To resolve this, you need to apply a patch to the Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveProvider, which handles the management of archived items. This provider stores archived item versions in a SQL database.
For detailed solution, you can refer to this blog:
https://sitecoresphere.wordpress.com/2024/04/25/allow-non-administrative-users-access-to-the-archive-folder/

Visibility of archived items is governed by the following method inside Sitecore.
Sitecore.Data.Archiving.Archive archive = ArchiveManager.GetArchive("archive", Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase);
User user = Sitecore.Context.User;
var archiveEntries = archive.GetEntriesForUser(user, 0, 10)

Inside the GetEntriesForUser method it returns only those archived items which are archived by the user.  Therefore in your case second user was able to see archived items because it was archived by that user or may be user is an administrator.

In order to allow the archived items to be visible to every users, you can create a role with read access to the below item on the core database.
/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Recycle Bin/Can See All Items


Once the users have access to above item, they can see all the items archived by other user as well.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
